# Vite pwa plugin not working in development environment for react apps

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, vite, vite-plugin-pwa

I'v already migrated from webpack to vite and used [vite pwa plugin](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/) to register a service worker.

My problem is that when I try to use a custom path for service worker, Vite will work fine in production, but in development cause 404 error.

here is my VitePwa vite.config.js:

```
VitePWA({
      srcDir: 'src',
      filename: 'sw.js',
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      strategies: 'injectManifest',
      injectManifest: {
        injectionPoint: undefined
      }
    }),
```

I already got that, in the development environment, vite pwa plugin is looking for sw.js in the public directory but I want it to get it from src

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the solution:

First, set type as module in `vitePwaPlugin` config in `devOptions`:

```
 devOptions: {
        enabled: true,
        type: 'module',
      },
```

and `vitePwaPlugin` will try to install `dev-sw.js?dev-sw`  file as a service worker.

Secondly, for handling registration I used registerSW from virtual:pwa-register

```
import { registerSW } from 'virtual:pwa-register';

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  registerSW();
}
```

Note, if you are using typescript, consider adding

`/// <reference types="vite-plugin-pwa/client" />`

to `global.d.ts` file (if you don't have this file, you can create it)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem here where my remote development environment wasn't working, but the reload prompt was working locally via `npm run build` and `npm run preview`.

The problem for me was that the remote environment didn't have HTTPS, so everything worked but the `useRegisterSW` function silently failed.

Enabled HTTPS and now it's working.

I'm using VitePWA with Vue3/Vite, but it's extremely similar across React/Vue etc. I have a minimal repo if anyone wants to see it https://github.com/agm1984/vue-vite-pwa-minimal-update-prompt

Comment: Your repo is the best resource I have found to quickly set up a fully functional example!
Though I don't understand why calling updateServiceWorker() does not also reload the page (which I had to do myself with a location.reload() in a 1000ms setTimeout).
What is the point of updating the service worker without reloading the page? Or why not instead update the service worker on BeforeUnloadEvent?

Comment: @user3803848 thanks!, If I remember correctly, the serviceworker has an internal function that handles the reload. In my example code, there is a function `updateServiceWorker` that you call to reload, so the actual window.reload part is handled by the library there. Maybe it works slightly differently in React compared to Vue.

Comment: actually it seems to depend on the device, also the type declaration file for updateServiceWorker confuses me:
``export function useRegisterSW(options?: RegisterSWOptions): {
  /**
  * Reloads the current window to allow the service worker take the control.
  * @param reloadPage From version 0.13.2+ this param is not used anymore.
  */
  updateServiceWorker: (reloadPage?: boolean) => Promise<void>
}``
param not used anymore, but it still automatically reloads on android...
so I do this as a failsafe:
`updateServiceWorker(true).then(() => {
  setTimeout(location.reload, 500)
})`